# Can I install zero clearance hinges on my refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator, hinges, clearance

I'm having my new kitchen installed. I have 2 fridges one next to the other. I asked the kitchen designer if it would be ok for the clearance and he said yes. And... it isn't and it's a nightmare. I can't open any fridge, 2 or 3 inches in between them are missing and given the setup there is no way I create that space.

Note: I'm not talking about opening both fridges at once, I just need to open one at a time

I remember visiting these fancy appliances store with $10k+ fridges that had zero clearance hinges (which I learned of at the time).

Question: can I just buy zero clearance hinges and replace the existing ones with those?

I got a Samsung Bespoke refrigerator (double doors) if that matters, but I'm generally asking if anyone has successfully done it on a "standard" double door fridge?

Let me know, thanks!

Comment: Did the designer actually specify the exact model of refrigerator? Or just put in a 30" or 36" or whatever space and say "insert refrigerator here"?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact just say 36" and 24" and "said refrigerator here"

Comment: Then you can't (unfortunately) blame the designer. Well, you could in the sense that arguably they *should* have mentioned those concerns. But it really ends up on you. The designer likely had **absolutely no idea** and just "yes, of course!" because that's what their marketing mind always says by default. In a *typical* installation, the refrigerator sticks out in front of the cabinets, so the doors won't hit the cabinets and there is no issue. For a truly flush installation or (as you found) two refrigerators side-by-side it is a real issue.

Comment: "I have 2 fridges one next to the other"  How much beer does one man need?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I disagree. Installing 2 fridges next to another is impossible with most models, therefore it was designer's duty to specify one.

Comment: If you have already pad the alleged designer, get your money back. If not, they don't get paid. Sheer incompetence, and lying to you about it.

Comment: Have you contacted _your_ refrigerator's manufacturer(s) to see if they offer one for _your_ refrigerator? It's highly unlikely that there's a generic kit that'll fit any fridge out there...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because appliance modification/fabrication is off topic here. It's a question for the manufacturer, not us.

Comment: "I got a Samsung Bespoke refrigerator" No, it does not seem to actually be 'bespoke'.

Comment: @GlenYates OP needs a bespoke one but all they got is Samsung "Bespoke"

Comment: thanks for everyone who answered and for some of the good jokes. Whether it's offtopic, tinkering/modifying appliances to fit your needs feels like DIY but understand if people can feel otherwise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

Hinges are a crucial part of fridge design and if the manufacturer doesn't offer alternative hinges for your model, you're out of luck. You would have be to hire someone to design, manufacture and install a new type of hinge just for you, at which point redesigning the kitchen again is more realistic.

French door refrigerators are especially demanding on hinges, as both doors must meet perfectly in the middle to form a seal.

I seriously doubt it's physically possible to have zero clearance hinges in a French door design. The zero on the hinge side comes from the door moving away from hinge. Single door designs have some space there, but French have another, closely fitting door.

Unfortunately, I think that your most realistic option is to either redesign part of the kitchen or replace one or both fridges with a narrower model(s).

Answer (score 7):

I don't see any *practical* solution. The [measurement guide](https://image-us.samsung.com/SamsungUS/home/home-appliances/pdf/WillitFit_RF29BB8600_V2.pdf) specifically refers to clearance next to walls (and recommends not installing next to a wall at all, if possible) and in addition the diagrams make it pretty clear that there is some clearance needed at the hinge side of the doors, not just clearance so that the door can swing > 90 degrees.

The hinges themselves are on the top and bottom, which is perfectly normal for refrigerators. Cabinets often have hinges in the middle so that they connect in the side of the cabinet instead of at the top & bottom, and those hinges are usually easy to replace, though possibly with some work on the door and/or cabinet - things like drilling new holes that you would definitely *not* want to do with a refrigerator door. In addition, anything that would affect how the door swings would likely affect how it seals, which is important for keeping food cold and for energy costs.

With a simple single door refrigerator (or really two doors - one for refrigerator, one for freezer) very often the doors/hinges can be swapped between the right side and the left side to fit your kitchen layout. But obviously that is not the case with a side-by-side refrigerator.

Obviously this could have been designed to handle it - e.g., a small filler space in between (perhaps a small floor to ceiling storage pantry cabinet) but retrofitting that after the kitchen is done is not so easy.

When I redid my kitchen, the refrigerator was last on the list (it wasn't dead yet!) so I arranged the kitchen with the new refrigerator area open on one side in order to allow for any size refrigerator, and that worked well for me. But I did my own design with a little free help from Home Depot and not a professional designer.

Answer (score 6):

You can't change the hinges to make it work...period.   The designer should have known that 2 refrigerators side by side would require certain design elements to be planned for them to be functional. They should have asked for specifications on the fridges for the design layout.

This angers me, as I have run into plenty of times a "designer" has planned a kitchen that would not fit the space allotted, or assumed that walls were going to be moved that were definitely not. (These designers had little experience.)

Go back to the "designer" and ask them what they recommend be done and still stay in budget. ( this just to put some pressures on them. They may come forth with some compensation)
Another option may be a European brand refrigerator that is only slightly more expensive than the common brands. Some of these have the zero clearance doors. But admittedly they are hard to find.  Sorry I don't remember the names. I will check and post back here.

You have a difficult dilemma.